# Access Routing using route name instead of routeTemplate in WebAPI2

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am new to Web API. I am creating sample application now and trying to understand routing in the same.

Here is my scenario:

I am having AuthorController and 2 action methods like:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAuthor(int id){//logic}
public IHttpActionResult GetAuthorByName(string name){//logic}
```

Here is default route:

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Now I want to access second method **GetAuthorByName** with different route like:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "routename",
            routeTemplate: "api/RandomName/GetAuthorByName/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Authors", action = "GetAuthorByName", id = RouteParameter.Optional }

        );
```

So that when I access http://localhost:1234/api/RandomName/GetAuthorByName?Title=Kajal it should call my controller & action method which I have pass in parameters.

Is this possible in Web API? Or how can I access my action method using route name?

Please note I use Rest client of Firefox to call method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in Web API. You can specify a route for that controller and action method. this can be done with [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) (introduced in Web API 2) or with [regular routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api).

Since you are using the regular routes, the parameter 'name' needs to be specified in the routeTemplate as shown below. If you register this route before the default route, the access URL to hit the action method will be.  http://localhost:1234/api/RandomName/GetAuthorByName/Kajal

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "routename",
            routeTemplate: "api/RandomName/GetAuthorByName/{name}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Authors", action = "GetAuthorByName", name = RouteParameter.Optional }

        );
```